# How to make a copy of a text file that located in another server

Tags: php

How to make a copy of a text file that located in another server , in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways that I can immediately think of:

```
file_put_contents('/my/path/file.txt', file_get_contents('http://www.example.org/test.txt'));
```

See the [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) and [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/file_put_contents) manual pages.

Or more succinctly:

```
copy('http://www.example.org/test.txt', '/my/path/file.txt')
```

See the [`copy()` manual page](http://php.net/copy).

Of course do not forget:

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen
>   wrappers have been enabled.

See the [`allow_url_fopen` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) for more information.

Comment: I am getting the error message

" failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"

Comment: The remote server is refusing to respond to your request from what I can see. There are many reasons this could be taking place. Perhaps the remote server doesn't want you downloading from them in this way?

Answer (score 1):

```
copy('http://yourdomine.com/souce.txt','your/path.txt')
```

Should work.

Comment: I am getting the error message

" failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"

Comment: Provably the file on the server is read only for the external users.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()`

Comment: I am getting the error message

" failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"

Comment: it could be that your hoster is blocking your request

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to read the remote file and write it into yours:

```
$f = fopen('myfile.txt','w'); 
fwrite($f, file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/myfile.txt')); 
fclose($f);
```